# Non-continuous higher differentiability, II

Tags: real-analysis

In a comment on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165349/non-continuous-higher-differentiability), Tom Goodwillie proposed a notion of higher differentiability that I elaborate to something like the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.  Let's say that $f$ is *strongly twice differentiable* at $x$ if there is a bilinear map $d^2 f_x:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ f(x+v+w) - f(x+v) - f(x+w) + f(x) = d^2f_x(v,w) + E(v,w){|v|}{|w|} $$

where $\lim_{v,w\to 0} E(v,w) = 0$.  He pointed out that such a $d^2 f_x$, if it exists, is symmetric, since the LHS above is symmetric in $v$ and $w$.  On the other hand, the usual proof of equality of mixed partials essentially shows that if $f$ is $C^2$ in a neighborhood of $x$, then it is strongly twice differentiable in this sense.

1. Does strong twice differentiability at $x$ imply that $f$ is differentiable at $x$?
2. If $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, does strong twice differentiability at $x$ imply that $f$ is twice differentiable in the usual sense, i.e. that $d f:U \to L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is differentiable at $x$?  Do we need $f$ to be strongly twice differentiable on a whole neighborhood $U$?
3. Can you give any reference for a definition such as this?

Comment: For 1, no: $f$ might be linear over $\mathbb Q$ but not over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming continuity?

Comment: Francois' comment reminds me of how, in topology, to define $n$-connected, you first require $k$-connected for all $k < n$.  That is, a simply connected space must first be connected, and so on.  Most likely whatever hopes you have for this shortcut to twice-differentiability will have this particular problem.

Comment: You may also be interested in Tom's answer to my question here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80724/taylors-theorem-and-the-symmetric-group

Comment: @RyanReich It is possible to define $n$-connected without defining $k$-connected first: just ask that the $n$-truncation be contractible.  I think there may be a similar solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Think of a $\mathbb Q$-linear map $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb Q$.
2. Yes. For small nonzero $v$ and $w$ write
   $$
   E(v,w)=\frac{f(a+v+w)-f(a+v)-f(a+w)+f(a)-b(v,w)}{|v||w|}.
   $$

By assumption you have bilinear $b$ such that the limit of $E(v,w)$ as $(v,w)\to (0,0)$ is zero. If you also assume that $f$ is differentiable at $a+v$ for all small enough $v$ then for small nonzero $v$ you can take the limit of $E(v,w)$ as $w\to 0$ and get
$$
\frac{df_{a+v}(\frac{w}{|w|})-df_{a}(\frac{w}{|w|})-b(v,\frac{w}{|w|})}{|v|}.
$$
The limit of this as $v\to 0$ is zero. Therefore the derivative of $x\mapsto df_x$ at $x=a$ exists and corresponds to $b$.

Note that this implies that you get continuity of $df$ at a point if you have existence of $df$ in a neighborhood of the point and existence of $d^2f$ (in the sense we are exploring) at the point.

Comment: Really, really dumb question: what's a nontrivial linear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb Q$-linear, sorry. I'll edit. But don't ask me for an example.

Comment: I understood it as $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, but does a nontrivial example exist? I'll settle for a proof that such an example exists.

Comment: Do you believe that every $\mathbb Q$ vector space has a basis?

Comment: Oy. Stuff like this gives me a headache. It reminds me why analysts and geometers avoid studying differentiable functions per se.

Comment: Do you know an example that shows you can't phrase this definition using the quadratic form instead of the bilinear map?  I.e. a differentiable function $f$ such that $f(x+2v)-2f(x+v)+f(x) = Q(v) + E(v) |v|^2$ for some quadratic form $Q$ and error $E(v)\to 0$, but $f$ is not twice differentiable?

Comment: All the examples given in the answers to your previous question ...

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks!  I am puzzled, however, because I just happened to be looking through Strichartz' *The Way of Analysis*, and on p181 after proving that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h^2} (f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+f(x)) = f''(x)$ for a $C^2$ function, he says "There is also a converse to this theorem, but it is much more difficult to prove."  Do you have any idea what he might have had in mind?

Comment: No idea. Except that it seems clear that the statement in question must have a hypothesis about this limit existing for all nearby $x$, not just for one $x$.

Comment: Yeah... but that's not enough, because the counterexamples $x^3 \sin(1/x)$ are smooth away from $0$.  Maybe if one asserts that the value of that limit is a continuous function of $x$?